# Roman Numeral Chords with Slash

Tags: chords, chord-theory, harmony, roman-numerals, chord-inversions

[This chart](http://www.readmusicfree.com/images/chordprogressionmap.png) has a listing for a chord V/1 and I'm having trouble interpreting this chord, specifically the "/1" part.  I think the "/1" part might have one of the following meanings...

- "the base note of the chord (in this case, the fifth note in the scale) as the lowest note"
- "the first note of the scale as the lowest note"
- "the first inversion of the chord"

What is the proper way to interpret V/1?

Comment: Exactly what is the chart purporting to show?

Comment: Look at part 5, where the same map is shown with actual chords. Much easier to understand !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this page](http://www.readmusicfree.com/ChordProgressionMap) where the image is given. Here you can select a key and click a chord in order to show the actual pitches of that chord.

For instance, "I/5" in C major is listed as `G C E G`. Since `G` is both scale-degree 5 and the chordal fifth, it's still unclear what 5 means. But when we see that "V/2" is listed as `D G B D`, we realize that **these integers refer to scale degrees**.

As a friendly PSA, beware of some of the pitches on this chart; their algorithm privileges flats over sharps, so chords are sometimes spelled a little strangely (e.g., they list E major as `E A♭ B`).

Comment: Have to say, the minute I see inaccuracies like Ab quoted in Emaj., I tend to dismiss the rest of the site as written by inexperts.